# Convert C# Path object to XAML in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF Path object which is created by reading nodes from a binary file, however I was wondering if there was a way to take this generated Path and convert it into XAML that could be stored in the application resources.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use XamlWriter (System.Windows.Markup)? It should be capable of taking any WPF object and producing a string containing the equivalent XAML.